# Unable to add PostgreSQL-12 repository on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, yum

While installing the PostgreSQL-12 repository on CentOS 7, I encountered the following problem. I attempted to download and install it, but without success. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
[root@localhost /]# sudo yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Cannot open: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm. Skipping.
Error: Nothing to do
```

CPU Details:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 78
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               2496.002
BogoMIPS:              4992.00
Hypervisor vendor:     VMware
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce that problem. Fetching the repository using `sudo yum install` works as does fetching it in a browser or with `curl`. If you try fetching that URL in a browser, does it work? If not, what is the error?